# Win7 query hardware keyboard Caps Lock current state

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter application with Python 2.7 on OS windows7.
I want to query the current state of the hardware keyboard Caps Lock without capturing keyboard events, sending them anywhere, or toggling it.

Does the OS keyboard interrupt handler take on a modal state when the user physically?

Presses the hardware keyboard caps lock key?, or is Caps Lock an internal logic state within
the keyboard itself?
is there a Python means to query the current state of Caps Lock?

I've been searching for YEARS, read thousands of posts relating to keyboards,
and all I find is keyboard event capturing and toggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetKeyState` is the Windows API that you would use to find out the current state of the capslock key in C/C++, so using ctypes you could do something like this:

```
import ctypes

VK_CAPITAL = 0x14

if ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 1:
    print "Caps Lock On"
else:
    print "Caps Lock Off"
```

And no, the capslock functionality isn't implemented in the keyboard itself. The keyboard just tells the computer when the Caps Lock key is pressed. Windows then keeps track of capslock state itself. It even has to tell the keyboard when to turn the capslock indicator on or off. The keyboard won't do this on its own.